# clang not detecting c++ headers on OS X

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, clang++

I'm trying to use clang to compile a simple hello world cpp file with our favorite `#include 'iostream'`

But clang, for some reason shows

> fatal error: 'iostream' file not found

This stumped me. Can anyone suggest what I must do (or if I need to change things by using cmake?)

**EDIT 1:**

Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

The compiler I'm using is NOT the apple clang that came with it, but another one that was built separately with OMP support. This is the website from where it was taken.

http://clang-omp.github.io/

when I type `clang -v` in the terminal, I get this output -

```
clang version 3.5.0 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Now this is the cpp file I'm trying to compile. A lame hello-world example -

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main() {

std::cout << "blah" ;
return 0;
}
```

And I used this command in the terminal to compile it -

```
clang Untitled.cpp -o blah
```

to get this error -

```
Untitled.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream.h' file not found
#include <iostream.h>
```

Comment: What is the command line you used to compile?

Comment: clang filename.cpp -o blah
I also tried building opencv using cmake. I couldn't 'make'it. Showed the same errors, for iostream.h, cstring, and other headers.

Comment: If you could post a minimal stub of your .cpp file and also the command you are using to invoke clang, that might allow us to help you directly. Also version info of the OS and compiler might be relevant but it's hard to guess with the level of detail provided.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry but I can only access that system in around 10 hours now. (Work) 
I'll try and get more information. This may not be a trivial problem, or might actually be.

Comment: You might try cmake, and let the tool sort out the dependancies. It solved my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try to

```
#include <iostream>
```

instead since that is the standard way.

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

is legacy from the mid-1990s which might not be supported.

Comment: That gives "unknown type name 'istream'; did you mean '::std::istream'"

Comment: from what code did you get that error message, the above mentioned hello world does not refer to it. using an unqualified name might require a using namespace std; or qualification as std::istream as the error message suggests.

Comment: makes no difference.  problem is deeper.  downvoted.

Answer (score -4):

Try make to compile:

```
make filename(without extension)
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What does `filename(without extension)` mean? How does this solve an error about `iostream`?